# how to get the position of an element in unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an unordered list and each list contains an anchor tag and a button.

On click of the button i want to get the position of the element which is clicked using javascript.

The code that i tried is :

```
function getEventTarget(e) {
         debugger
    e = e || window.event;
    return e.target || e.srcElement; 
}

var ul = document.getElementById('subMenu5');
    ul.onclick = function (event) {
    debugger
    var target = getEventTarget(event);
    alert(target.index);
};
```

But this doesnt throw the index or position of the element that is selected

Comment: You are right mate. I didn't get the question. ps: Call me Praveen. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `li` that was triggered by looking up the `.closest()` parent that has the tag `li` and then find out what is its `.index()`

```js
$('button,a').click(function(){
  var li = $(this).closest('li');
  console.log("You clicked on item ",(li.index()+1));
});
```

```css
a
{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><button>I am button 1</button><a href="#">I am a link 1</a></li>
  <li><button>I am button 2</button><a href="#">I am a link 2</a></li>
  <li><button>I am button 3</button><a href="#">I am a link 3</a></li>
  <li><button>I am button 4</button><a href="#">I am a link 4</a></li>
  <li><button>I am button 5</button><a href="#">I am a link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi this is what i want but i am not able to do. I have a javascript function and inside that i wrote the code  var li = $(this).closest('li');
  console.log("You clicked on item ",(li.index()+1)); but this always throws 0